# VirtueMart PayPal Checkout Advanced Credit Card form is incomplete

Tags: joomla-4.x, virtuemart

Joomla ‎4.3.4

VM 4.2.2

VM PayPal Checkout 4.2.2

VM PayPal 4.2.2

We have been using the VM PayPal plugin for a while now and are in the process of changing to PayPal Checkout so that we get to use the advanced credit card option from PayPal that uses the more updated version of the PayPal API.
We have set up the account with the help and confirmation from the PayPal team for the new options needed, but when we select and publish this payment method, the form for the payment that is shown in the front is not a working one:

[image: Form for Advanced credit card]

In this form, there should be PayPal buttons, but not only are these buttons missing, but the space for the credit card information (Number, Exp. Date, CVV) is empty without input.
The settings for the plugin are:
Payment Method Information:

[image: Plugin general information]

Configuration:

[image: Plugin Configurations (1)]
[image: Plugin Configurations (2)]

Within the errors we found, there was a debug message saying, “Paypal Hosted Fields Not eligible,” but we got confirmation that the account was approved for these fields.

[image: Code where the debug is printed]

We would appreciate any help with this issue.

I appreciate any help you can provide.